# Returning 200 status code though WriteHeader was used to return another status code

Tags: http, go

I'm writing a post endpoint and in my error handling I want to return a 400.

```
log.Println("Artifact post requested")
// Check for valid JSON Body
body, err := getJSONBody(r)
if err != nil {
  log.Println("we got an error")
  log.Println(err)
  w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
  return
}

func getJSONBody(r *http.Request) ([]byte, error) {
    if r.Body == nil {
        fmt.Println("body has issues")
        return nil, errors.New("Received an empty body")
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()

    // Read body
    body, readErr := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if readErr != nil {
        return nil, readErr
    }
    return body, nil
}
```

But when I run unit tests I get a 200 instead of 400. Any ideas why this may happen?
[Test output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4gvS.png)

Comment: You have to call `WriteHeader` before writing anything to the body. The code does not show. If you are writing some bytes before `WriteHeader`, the header may have already been sent.

Comment: I don't write anything to body. I only read then return if its valid (getJSONBody). I only use WriteHeader if there's an error and return immediately

Comment: Show your unit tests

Comment: The fact that you are getting a 200 means you are writing something else, or not hitting this code at all. Please create a [mre].

Comment: Yea, it's an issue with Unit tests, I make two requests in a row, but if I only make one the test passes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was something wrong with the Unit tests, making multiple requests failed but making a single request passed (got the 400 I was looking for).